# Camel File Consumer when folder is not accessible

Tags: apache-camel

Hy all,

when using the file consumer on a folder, which the camel context does not have access to (e.g. using `chmod a-rwx test/locked`) the context starts as normal (not even warnings) but also doesn't pick up any files in the folder (well, how should it).

Is there a way to have the file component thrown an error on startup (or at least on polling the folder), when it can't access the folder?

Otherwise I will have to check it using manual java code before configuring the route, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks and greets
Chris

Comment: No there is no such support currently. You are referring to the starting directory you setup in the camel file endpoint? We could maybe add support for this. You are welcome to log a JIRA and work on a patch/PR for such a new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on executing the following code before the route is configured and thus making sure it can be accessed:

```java
Path path = Paths.get(folderPath);
// The only case we do not allow is when the folder exists and is not readable
boolean canAccess = !Files.exists(path) || Files.isReadable(path);
if (!canAccess) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not initialize route, because folder \""
      + baseFolder + "\" can not be accessed. This might happen when it does not exist "
      + "or there are no read permission for the current user");
}
```

I also created an issue in the apache jira to add the feature in the future:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13483

Thanks everbody for the suggestions
Chris

Answer (score 2):

*Otherwise I will have to check it using manual java code before configuring the route, which I would like to avoid.*

You can use a PollingConsumerPollStrategy with the endpoint to check the whether the path has access issues, then raise error.

```
public class FileAccessPollingConsumerPollStrategy extends DefaultPollingConsumerPollStrategy{
   public boolean begin(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint) {

File pollingDirectory = ((FileEndpoint) endpoint).getFile();

//check your access with poillingDirectory and raise any error.

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then configure your camel endpoint - `from("file://inbox/?pollStrategy=#fileAccessPollingConsumerPollStrategy")`

Comment: Ah good point, likely where we could consider adding such functionality to the default implementation

Comment: If I understand the pollStrategy correctly, then this code is executed every time the polling is done (with the file components default being half a second), which would mean, that the error is raised twice per second and the spams the log, with the alternative being to stop the route (or even the context) in that code, which doesn't really sound like a great idea...
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah that is correct, so you want this to happen only once during startup, and cause Camel to fail starting all together?

Comment: I think you can inject Router controller or the camel context to stop the route in the begin() method of FileAccessPollingConsumerPollStrategy if it encounters access issue. By the way, @Claus-Ibsen is a legend in the camel world, he might have a better suggestion.